# Calculate max height in Lua

Tags: math, lua

I'm trying to get the maximum height at which an object was thrown, but it gives me an erroneous result

I made this:

```
local Vo = 10^2
local a = math.sin(30)^2
local g = 10*2
local H = Vo*a/g
print(H)
```

Expected: 1.25
Results: 4.88

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem began when you assumed that `math.sin` takes **degrees** as argument. It does not. It takes **radians**:

```
local Vo = 10^2
local a = math.sin(math.rad(30))^2
local g = 10*2
local H = Vo*a/g
print(H)
-- 1.25
```

Please refer to [lua-users wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial) or other references while using functions you have never used before. It really helps.